# Is it ok to have multiple files table for a different entity?

Tags: mysql, database-design, design-pattern

I have two entities A and B.

A and B can have multiple files associated to them, each of those files can be a `document` or an `image`.

Does it make sense to create `a_files` and `b_files` tables with the the following structure?

`id | a_id | url | type(enum)`

`id | b_id | url | type(enum)`

I thought about creating a generic `files` table too and then reference it through `a/b_files`, but it seems to me a kind of over-killing joins.

Comment: Confusing terminology.  In database context, an "entity" is a "table" with many rows.  It is not two rows in a single table.  For example A and B can be "students" and "classes" -- many:many relationship.  Or "classes" and "textbook" -- one:many.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I meant a "table" when I said "entity".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your two tables are exactly the same in structure then very likely they should be a single table. Your example with two separate tables appears redundant making it more work to maintain in the long run and potentially more error prone.

"*I thought about creating a generic files table too and then reference it through a/b_files, but it seems to me a kind of over-killing joins.*" - Design your tables in the way that makes the most logical sense to your use cases and object structure, worry about performance after that *if* it's even necessary. Modern relational database systems can handle large numbers of rows just fine when indexed properly, even when joining.

Generically speaking, it sounds like all you need is a single table defined as `(id, url, type, entity_id)`.

Comment: Thank you @J.D. Would having a single table with multiple foreign keys but only one of them filled a wrong way to go? Something like: `id | url | type | a_id | b_id`

Comment: @FedericoPeralta you shouldn't need the redundant fields `a_id` and `b_id` rather just have generic field `entity_id` that stores the ID of the referenced entity.